# Can I tell the QB64 compiler *not* to optimize my code?

Tags: compiler-optimization, basic, qbasic, qb64

I want to experiment with the efficiency of various algorithms and compiler optimization is an obstacle. Can I disable compiler optimizations in QB64?

Comment: You'd need to have a look at the `<qb64dir>/internal/c/makeline_<os>.txt` file and remove the `-O<n>` switch, but there's currently no way to disable or otherwise alter the optimization level through the IDE or command-line options.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune No that's perfect, thanks! That does exactly what I wanted, if you post it as an answer I will gladly accept.